# Sync iPhone in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iphone, sync

I want to sync music on my iPhone 4 (version 4.3.3) with Ubuntu 11.04.

Is there any working way to do that?

I've already tried Amarok, Banshee, and iTunes on wine. None of them work.

Answer (score -1):

Installing libimobiledevice worked for a user on this forum: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/alternative-to-itunes-to-connect-iphone-to-ubuntu-11-04-a-887116/

Comment: I do confirm: http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-To-Sync-Your-iPhone-Device-in-Ubuntu-10-10-169608.shtml